# ASP .NET DynamicData Custom Provider

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, dynamic-data

I'm implementing a custom DynamicData provider for ASP .NET, but for the life of me, I can't figure out where in the API to define how my custom provider should do saves/updates/inserts...

For my custom provider, I've created:

```
DataModelProvider
TableProvider
ColumnProvider
AssociationProvider
```

and an `IDisposable` DataContext (which is where my save method is)...

But I don't see how I can wire up DynamicData to my DataContext's save method...

Sorry, I know this seems simple, and I was about to reflector some code to check it out, but I figured I'd ask here first.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just started out on the same path.

Don't have an answer yet, but some clues might be found here:

http://hestia.typepad.com/flatlander/2008/12/aspnet-dynamic-data-and-custom-sources.html

**Quoting:**

> .. in Global.asax.cs, you will of course need to pass an instance of your DataModelProvider instead of a LINQ to SQL DataContext..